# MVC 5 Model. Making Enum properties unique/Ranked. Validation force unique values to properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, properties, enums, unique

I have this enum RankValue and the properties IntroAnswers1 -5 which becomes a dropdown selector in my view. This is all fine. But what I want is to force the user to input unique values:

Only one A, one B, one C, one D, one E -selected.

Is it possible to do this with validation in my Model?
What would you recommend as good practice to solve this?

```
//enum rank
//SCOPE REACES WHOLE NAMESPACE
public enum RankValue
{
    a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, e=5
}

public class IntroResponse
{
    [Required()]
    public RankValue? IntroAnswer1 { get; set; }
    [Required()]
    public RankValue? IntroAnswer2 { get; set; }
    [Required()]
    public RankValue? IntroAnswer3 { get; set; }
    [Required()]
    public RankValue? IntroAnswer4 { get; set; }
    [Required()]
    public RankValue? IntroAnswer5 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest thing to do is to define custom validation rule for your model. For that you can implement `IValidatableObject` interface. Below I've written some variation of what could be done, but it is definitely not perfect so feel free to adjust it to your needs.

```
public class IntroResponse : IValidatableObject
{
    ...
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) 
    {
        IList<RankValue?> answers = new List<RankValue?>{IntroAnswer1, IntroAnswer2, ...};
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        if (answers.Where(a => a == RankValue.a).Count() >= 2)
        {
            results.Add(new ValidationResult("a can be used only once!"));
        }
        ...
        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would I put this code in the Controller as a new separate class?

Comment: @JuliusHolmberg, this is the same model class you already have defined, just extended to implement an interface

Comment: It is giving me an Error message:

"Some invalid arguments" on the List

Comment: The best overloaded Add method 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AppName>.Add(AppName.Models.RankValue)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments

Comment: @JuliusHolmberg, sorry, did not notice that your properties are nullables. Fixed

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. You forgot to put one '?' but you really helped me here! Thank you.

Comment: @JuliusHolmberg, forgotten '?' added